# LLVM: Clang does not run Pass if CallGraphWrapperPass is a requirement

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I wrote the following *pass* for llvm.

```
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
    struct SkeletonPass : public FunctionPass {
        static char ID;
        SkeletonPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

        void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
            AU.addRequired<CallGraphWrapperPass>();
            AU.setPreservesAll();
        }

        virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
            errs() << "Function: " << F.getName() << "!\n";

            CallGraph &CG = getAnalysis<CallGraphWrapperPass>().getCallGraph();

            return false;
        }
    };
} 

char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<SkeletonPass> X("skeleton", "text");
```

If I execute this code with

```
opt -load ./libSkeletonPass.so -skeleton test.bc > /dev/null
```

I get the correct output. (test.bc can be neglected)

According to this great [blog](http://adriansampson.net/blog/clangpass.html), the next command

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang ./libSkeletonPass.so test.c
```

should also work, as long as we replace the last line with:

```
static void registerSkeletonPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                         legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new SkeletonPass());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
  RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                 registerSkeletonPass);
```

The **problem** is that clang crashes and returns this error:

```
...
clang-3.8: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang-3.8: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
...
```

Without all the *CallGraphWrapperPass* references clang executes the *pass* correct.

I'm new to llvm, so is there something I missed?

**System**: Linux 4.4.0 (64bit)

**clang version**: 3.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change EP_EarlyAsPossible to EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0.